# Play single track spotify sdk

Tags: android, kotlin, spotify

I am using the [Spotify android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/), and I am trying to get a single song to play, and I would like to potentially play a song after the current one is completed. The issue is that after the song completes Spotify plays a random song afterwards. Is it possible to play the song and not have anything else automatically play after it?

I am simply calling the app remotes player API play function,

```
mSpotifyAppRemote?.getPlayerApi()?.play(uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mikee you are doing nothing wrong, Spotify messes around with track replay if you are only using the Free version, if you use Premium it will work correctly. Funny enough if you try playing by an alblum or artist that works with the Free version.

Comment: OMG thank u so much. But where did u get this info from?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but from [their documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/) it looks like you could watch the `PlayerState`. I'm also not sure when a `PlayerState` event would trigger but if it's coming back relatively often you could check the `track` value and see if it's gone to `null`, or another value and work using that.

**Here's a Java example from their website:**

```
// Subscribe to PlayerState
        mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi()
                .subscribeToPlayerState()
                .setEventCallback(new Subscription.EventCallback<PlayerState>() {

            public void onEvent(PlayerState playerState) {
                // See what values are in playerState, might be able to determine 
                // if it's now randomly playing?
                final Track track = playerState.track;
                if (track != null) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", track.name + " by " + track.artist.name);
                    // If the track is now different, your song has finished, stop it?
                }
            }
        });
```

I've put a few extra comments in the code above that might yield some results!

Comment: Thanks, the issue is I have tried this in the passed, the value rarely goes to null, it usually goes to another track, I can listen to this change and stop the next track, the problem is that the next track will still audibly play for around a second

Comment: @Mikee Ah, what other event listeners does the API provide? If it provides one for current track information, are you able to get the duration of the song you're making it currently play and then sleep and stop the sound after that duration?

Comment: The issue with that is it still doesn't prevent the other tracks from playing

Comment: @Mikee Couldn't you get the duration of the track you want to play as soon as you start playing it, then use a timer to stop the Spotify output 1 second before its due to stop? That way nothing else would play.